# after user had entered value update number to include commas

Tags: matlab

I am creating a GUI in Matlab.

I have an edit text box where the user can enter a value. The value will be numeric. What I would like to do though is after the user has finished entering the value to update the value in the following manner...

```
 If they enter the value 5000000 I would want the text box to update to 5,000,000
```

I have to say I'm somewhat struggling with making a GUI in Matlab. I can't seem to find an event like lostFocus. Is this possible in Matlab?

Comment: You are looking for the [Callback function](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/add-code-for-components-in-callbacks.html#f10-1001464)! Note that user has to presse Enter after having entered the text.

Comment: @Zep I see, thanks for that. What if they tab or click elsewhere will that function be called?

Comment: From the page I linked: "When the user types characters inside the text field and presses the Enter key, the callback function [...]". However, I tried on a quick GUI and it works both with tab and outside click.

Comment: thanks it works! If you submit an answer I will mark it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the [Callback function](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/add-code-for-components-in-callbacks.html#f10-1001464). For the edit box, it will be called after the user presses Enter, tabs out of the box or clicks elsewhere.

In your case, something like this will work

```
function edit1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    % hObject    handle to edit1 (see GCBO)
    % eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
    % handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

    input = get(hObject,'String');
    display(input);
```